# Get sum of two fields when the Other fields are the Same - Linq

Tags: c#, linq

this is my query:

```
var query = from buy in db.tblCustomerBuys.AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
                Year = Convert.ToInt32(buy.BuyDate.Substring(0, 4)),
                ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(buy.ProductID),
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(buy.TotalPrice),
                Amount = Convert.ToDouble(buy.Amount),
                Major = (Convert.ToBoolean(db.tblCustomers.First(x => x.CustomerID == buy.CustomerID).IsMajor) == true ? "Major" : "Normal"),
                Month = ClassDate.MonthName(Convert.ToInt32(buy.BuyDate.Split('/')[1])),
                Season = ClassDate.SeasonName(Convert.ToInt32(buy.BuyDate.Split('/')[1]))
            };
```

the table is about customers' buys. I need to get sum of price and amount for each product Id where all of the other fields are the same. Currently the output is for each row in the table.

for example for Product 1 we have:

```
Year: 2012, ID: 1, Price: 12000, Amount: 2k, Major: Normal, Month: 2, Season: 1
Year: 2012, ID: 1, Price: 10000, Amount: 3k, Major: Normal, Month: 2, Season: 1
```

as you can see all of the other fields than Price and Amount are the same,in this case I need to get sum of price and amount:

```
Year: 2012, ID: 1, Price: 22000, Amount: 5k, Major: Normal, Month: 2, Season: 1
```

so the output records will be less. How can I do this in a fast way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  You need to use a GroupBy to get all products with same year and id.  Yo may aslo need to group the Major, Month, and Season.

```
var totals = query.GroupBy(x => new { year = x.Year, id = x.ProductID }).Select(x => new {
                Year = x.Key.year,
                ProductID = x.Key.id,
                Price = x.Sum(y => y.Price),
                Amount = x.Sum(y => y.Amount),
                Major = x.First().Amount,
                Month = x.First().Month,
                Season = x.First().Season
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: it is working. But do u know any way making this query as fast as possible?

Comment: Doing a stored procedure in the database will speed up the query.

Answer (score 3):

1-You do not need to use AsEnumerable(), this will result in fetching all the data to the memory which might not be necessary. If it is possible to fetch only the grouping result, that might be much faster, see the next point.

2-You need Group by

```
db.tblCustomerBuys.
        .GroupBy(buy => new 
        {
            Year = Convert.ToInt32(buy.BuyDate.Substring(0, 4)),
            ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(buy.ProductID),
            Major = (Convert.ToBoolean(db.tblCustomers.First(x => x.CustomerID == buy.CustomerID).IsMajor) == true ? "Major" : "Normal"),
            Month = ClassDate.MonthName(Convert.ToInt32(buy.BuyDate.Split('/')[1])),
            Season = ClassDate.SeasonName(Convert.ToInt32(buy.BuyDate.Split('/')[1]))
        })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Year = x.Key.Year,
            ProductID = x.Key.ProductId,
            Price = x.Sum(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Price)),
            Amount = x.Sum(i => Convert.ToDouble(i.Amount)),
            Major = x.Key.Major,
            Month = x.Key.Month,
            Season = x.Key.Season
        }).ToList();
```

Please remember that if you run this in EF core (as of the time of writing this answer), all the data will be fetched to the memory and then groupped, which is much slower than if it was done in DBMS. This might not be an issue for you, also no an issue in EF6.x

Comment: While removing `AsEnumerable()` is a good general advice, in this specific case with all these `Convert`, `Split`, array index accessors etc. I doubt EF6 can translate it to SQL.

Comment: @Alireza thanks, but it gives me this error: `A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause`

Comment: I'm glad you read my posting and figured out you needed a groupby.  There is no need to modify the original query.  Just make 2nd query for the totals like I did.

Comment: you need to delete `from buy in ` from beginning.

Comment: @jdweng Please check the Answer times (by hovering the mouse over answered...), mine is earlier by 10 minutes. Unlike you, I won't judge you.

Comment: Your first response did not not have GroupBy.  I had my answer posted before you made your changes.

Comment: @jdweng Not sure if you can see the post history, but I can, so I can confirm that `GroupBy` **is** in the very first version of the answer. It had 2 UV when I was commenting and you posted yours. Hence technically speaking your answer is duplicate of this, so it's strange to be offensive to the answerer - OP accepted yours, fine - it's their choice, let move on. I would friendly suggest you deleting the comments under this post.